# Simplify __VA_ARGS__ issue: cannot extract NULL

Tags: c++, variadic, args

i got the following code:

header file:

```
  #define html(...) anyHtml(__VA_ARGS__, NULL);
  const char* Html::anyHtml(const char* arg, ...);
  #define body(cssClass, ...) anyBody(cssClass, __VA_ARGS__, NULL);
  const char* Html::anyBody(const char* cssClass, const char* arg, ...);
```

cpp file:

```
const char* Html::anyHtml(const char* arg, ...) {
string temp = initOpen + tagToString.at(HTML) + end + lf + lf;
va_list arguments;
for (va_start(arguments, arg); arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(arguments, const char*)) {
temp += arg + lf;
}
va_end(arguments);
temp += deOpen + tagToString.at(HTML) + end + lf;
string *returnThis = new string(temp);
return (*returnThis).c_str();
}

const char* Html::body(const char* cssClass, const char* arg, ...) {
string temp = initOpen + tagToString.at(BODY) + " class=\"" + cssClass + "\"" + end + lf + lf;
va_list arguments;
for (va_start(arguments, arg); arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(arguments, const char*)) {
temp += arg + lf +lf;
}
va_end(arguments);
temp += deOpen + tagToString.at(BODY) + end + lf;
string *returnThis = new string(temp);
return (*returnThis).c_str();
}
```

main file:

```
Html *html = new Html();

cout << html -> html("test","test","test");
cout << html -> body("thisClass","test","test");
```

works fine!!

BUT THIS:

```
Html *html = new Html();

cout << html -> html(
    "hello",
    html -> body("thisClass","content")
    );
```

dont work..
if i outcomment the macro for anyBody in the header file

```
//#define body(cssClass, ...) anyBody(cssClass, __VA_ARGS__, NULL);
```

it is possible like this:

```
Html *html = new Html();

cout << html -> html(
    "hello",
    html -> body("thisClass","content",NULL)
    );
```

now my questions:

is it possible to nest some macros like

```
#define body(cssClass, ...) anyBody(cssClass, __VA_ARGS__, NULL);
```

among themselves ?

i´ve read that the whole "variable argument count" thing is still not really designed in cpp today?

if you take a look at the functions anyHtml() and anyBody(). is this a "good" solution for this issue or is it some kind of a dirty newbe hack? i´m still new to cpp coming along with perl and java mostly.. for this i want to get some feedback to get further with it..

now.. enough :-)

your welcome to tell me what u want to say.. :-)

---- EDIT

ok i´m sorry..

```
Html *html = new Html();

cout << html -> html(
    "hello",
    html -> body("thisClass","content")
    );
```

the output should be

```
<html>
hello
<body class="thisClass">
content
</body>
</html>
```

but it gives

```
C2143 Syntax Error missing ')' before ';'
C2143 Syntax Error missing ')' before ';'
C2059 Syntax Error: ')'
```

if i use both

```
#define html(...) anyHtml(__VA_ARGS__, NULL);
#define body(cssClass, ...) anyBody(cssClass, __VA_ARGS__, NULL);
```

if i make

```
cout << html -> html("hello","test");
cout << html -> body("thisClass","content");
```

these errors not appearing..

without this macros i have to type this:

```
 cout << html -> html(
    "hello",
    html -> body("thisClass","content",NULL)
    );
```

very special i know.. :-(

--- EDIT

thanks for fixing my issue!

the semicolon in the macro definition solved the nesting problem...

what about the functions anyHtml() and body()...

is it correct with using the

```
string temp = ...
```

and casting it after the string operations?

or is it dirty?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Do you really always put spaces around your `->` operators like that?  That's a style choice I've never seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extraneous semicolon's in your macros. Remove them:

```
#define html(...) anyHtml(__VA_ARGS__, NULL)
#define body(cssClass, ...) anyBody(cssClass, __VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

If you don't remove them, you end up with syntax errors, because the expansion turns into something like this:

```
cout << html -> anyHtml(
    "hello",
    html -> anyBody("thisClass", "content", NULL);, NULL);;
```

**Edit:** You asked:

> Is it correct with using the `string temp = ...` and casting it after the string operations? or is it dirty?

You are not casting `temp`, but creating a copy of it in dynamically allocated memory. Although this allows you to pass back a valid C string, it is creating a memory leak, since you will not be able to call `delete` on the object you created.

You can just change your routines to return `std::string`, and then you can return `temp` directly without without needing dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You've got semicolons following your macro definitions, so you end up with a semicolon in your argument list for

```
cout << html -> html(
  "hello",
  html -> body("thisClass","content")
  );
```